# Pass parameter through routerLink to a new component

Tags: html, angular, parameters, routes, components

I want to send a variable once pressing the link provided inside the list-profile html doc. The current code doesn't work and it crashes. I can provide with more details if needed.

list-profile.component.html

```
<div class="col col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <ul  id="list_of_users">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" *ngFor="let user of users"><a [routerLink]="['/profile', user.id]"  routerLinkActive="active" (click)="testFunc(user.id)">{{user.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'addProfile', component: AddProfileComponent },
{ path: 'listProfiles', component: ListProfilesComponent},
{ path: 'profile:id', component: ProfileComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the Routes to the following

```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'addProfile', component: AddProfileComponent },
    { path: 'listProfiles', component: ListProfilesComponent},
    { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent} // change to this
    ];
```

**Update To Access the value**

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}


ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe( params =>
        console.log(params['id'];
    )
}
```

Note - If you are using Angular (v4) please change param to paramMap

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore! But where do I fetch the variable? inside the constructor?

Comment: either inside constructor or ngOnInit

Comment: Could you provide with code example? Because atm the component says: Class 'ProfileComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'. Types of property 'ngOnInit' are incopatible. Type '(id: string) => void' is not assignable of type '() => void.

Comment: you need  to implement onInit in the component and then use it , i updated the answer

Comment: This did it! Thanks